# Check if user as a link in custom status/about me

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to create a command that returns all users of a server with a link in their custom status/about me. I tried searching on google but I found nothing. Thank you so much:)

Comment: The users on stack overflow arent here to spoonfeed you and write code for you, instead we are here to give you hints/guides on solving singular issues. Show that youve tried some effort into solving your questions such as providing us with code which youve tried or something alike.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would usually not spoonfeed someone code like this but I hope you take this as a chance to take a brake and try to understand how the code works and why.

I left in some useful comments to guide you through the code.

IMPORTANT: To run the code below you need to use these intents: `Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS` `Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES` and have them enabled in your application dashboard

```
// Get all members in the guild and let discord.js know we want to have their presence in the result
const members = await msg.guild.members.fetch({ withPresences: true });

// Loop through the members and call the function for every member inside the members list
members.forEach(async (member) => {
    if (
        // Does the user have a presence? if not hes maybe offline?
        !member.presence ||
        // User has a presence, check if he has any activities on his profile
        member.presence.activities.length <= 0 ||
        // The first activity is always a custom status, so we can check if user has a custom status set
        member.presence.activities[0].id != 'custom'
    )
        // If any of the above is true, we can skip this member
        return;

    // Get their custom status
    const activity = member.presence.activities[0];

    // Check if activity.state has a valid url
    if (
        // Check if the activity has a state, might be undefined
        !activity.state ||
        // Check if the activity state has a url inside it
        !activity.state.match(/^https?:\/\//)
    )
        return;

    // Here we can do whatever we want! For now we only log this to the console
    console.log(`${member.user.username} has custom status with url: ${activity.state}`);
});
```